# How to make text dark

Tags: plugins, leaflet

I am using the Leaflet map api and I downloaded and installed the 'leaflet-routing-machine' plugin just yesterday.  The problem is the square window on the right has only white text so nothing can be read in the route directions.   Has anyone else experienced this with this plugin?
How would you change it?

I tried re-linking the librairies and everything seems linked correctly.

I expect the routing instructions to appear in black font color instead of white is all, so that  they can be read.
Thanks,

Les

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding this to your CSS:

```
.leaflet-right {
    color: #000000;
}
```

You may also try this:

```
.leaflet-touch .leaflet-control-layers, .leaflet-touch .leaflet-bar {
    color: #000000;
}
```

Depending on what is overlaying the white text styles you might need to use `!important` in the given code.

Comment: ooops pressed return  for line break...how do I upvote your answer?

Comment: You up-voted it correctly. Thank you, I am glad you found a solution.